# Forcing onLayout on React Native view

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a React Native `View` containing a `Text` field, and I'm using the [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.35/view.html#onlayout) prop to do some positional calculations which rely on the data it provides.

```js
<View onLayout={this.calculateDimensions}>
  <Text>{this.props.content}</Text>
</View>
```

This works well, but there is a scenario where the `content` prop updates to a different string with the same character size. This results in the layout not changing and `onLayout` not triggering.

These positional calculations must occur each time the `content` prop updates.

**Note:** I am aware there are numerous ways to make the component update. Updating is not the same as laying out and sadly does not trigger `onLayout`.

Comment: If all else fails, have you tried using `content` as `key` for `View`? An entirely new `View` component will be created every time `content` changes though, but it might be worth it depending on the use case. `<View onLayout={this.calculateDimensions} key={this.props.content}>`

Comment: @CAJE Have you managed to figure this out? I'm currently trying to get onLayout event fired on a specific moment using PanResponder. Let me know if you have any insights. Thanks!

Comment: @SebastijanDumančić I'm afraid I don't have any insight beyond Tholle's hack. I had to resort to that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can have a unique key based on the content. whenever a key attribute of a component changes it is forcing a re-render.

Comment: This post must be accepted as an answer. Thank you Tom.

Comment: My comment is a bit late but this is so helpful, thank you @Tom Slutsky

Answer (score -1):

Method `this.calculateDimensions` needs to have some kind of indication, that it should be called again and fire re-render. I would recommend to use for its state or memo.

Let me show you an example with React Hooks. I'm setting for component `onLayout`, which using callback onComponentLayout. `onComponentLayout` has state `componentHeight`, which fire re-render whenever it's changed. So I'm able to change it dynamically if componentHeight is missing.

```
...
const onComponentLayout = useCallback(({nativeEvent: {layout}}) => {
   !componentHeight && setComponentHeight(layout.height);
}, [componentHeight, setComponentHeight]);
...

return (
...
    <Component
      onLayout={onComponentLayout}
    />
...
)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.